# Need timestamps for the completion of each stage in a work process flow

Tags: javascript, vba, timestamp

I'm using a MS SharePoint-based Intranet site to track and report the status of a requisition as it moves through its review processes.  There are six stages in the process flow and, for performance management purposes, I'd like to record a timestamp when each stage has been completed by its reviewing agent.

Each review action is represented by a choice column and I've created a corresponding calculated column, tied to the completion of each review stage, which includes the NOW() formula as follows:

```
   =IF([Review stage 1]="Concur",NOW(),""); 
   =IF([Review stage 2]="Concur",NOW(),""); 
   =IF([Review stage 3]="Concur",NOW(),"");
```

etc...

Unfortunately, since NOW() is a dynamic date function, this won't work for me.  I need a solution that will "lock in" a static timestamp at the completion of each review stage.

Any ideas on a viable solution?  I'd ideally like to use the calculated formula approach, if possible, but I'm open to other options.  I've read suggestions about using SharePoint versioning functionality, adding javascript, and (in the MS Excel resources) VBA code and circular reference formulas.

Thanks for any guidance you can provide...

Answer (score 0):

1. Capture the date/time of the review on the review form.
2. On moving through the workflow, move the value from that field to a specified field for reporting.
3. Wipe the field used for capture (optional)